# How can I solve this probably using integer linear programming?

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

We have four events x,y,z,w that could be ran on a machine M. Each of the event need to use 1/3 of the machine’s capacity. Some of them cannot be ran simultaneously in one batch (say x and y cannot be ran in one batch), how to determine the minimum number of batches expected to run? The time of the event does not matter so the objective is the minimum number of batches.

My intuition is I can formulate it as a integer linear programming. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are missing some information. What's the objective? What is the machines capacity? How long are the events, if that matters?

Comment: You're also missing that "certain capacity" per event. If they all are 1/3 capacity, the number of events is just 3.

Comment: @cricket_007 updated

Comment: There are four events.

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking. What is the definition of a batch? A collection of events? What defines the completion of an event? Why can't they run in parallel if they only take 1/3 capacity?

Comment: They can run in parallel but there are certain constraints say that event x and event y can't run simultaneously, so we have to run x,z,w in one batch and y in another batch. If a set of events could be executed by a machine simultaneously, this is called one batch.

Comment: @cricket_007 See above.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand. I'm sure you could define a linear programming model, but 1) I'm very inexperienced at it and 2) the problem is vaguely defined. You say there are 4 events. You say there are certain conditions preventing these from running in parallel. Are these facts, or you are making them up? You also have not specified if all events are required to be assigned. I'd suggest seeing if this helps  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: That's very easy to formulate as MIP. Where exactly is the problem? And why not show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, the **minimal** number of events that can be run is 0, as you didn't mention any objective function as mentioned by @cricket_007.
Then the **maximal** number of events is less than 2, as you mentioned at least two events can not be run simultaneously.
At last, the definition of batch is not given, so not sure about that.